# Get Request from POST in Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to modify the simple example in the [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd) part of Firebase functions to read the body of the (POST) request rather than the parameters of a GET request as written.

Here is the unmodified example:

```js
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
exports.addmessage = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const writeResult = await getFirestore()
      .collection("messages")
      .add({original: original});
  // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});

// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:documentId/original
// and saves an uppercased version of the message
// to /messages/:documentId/uppercase
exports.makeuppercase = onDocumentCreated("/messages/{documentId}", (event) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
  const original = event.data.data().original;

  // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `event.params`
  logger.log("Uppercasing", event.params.documentId, original);

  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();

  // You must return a Promise when performing
  // asynchronous tasks inside a function
  // such as writing to Firestore.
  // Setting an 'uppercase' field in Firestore document returns a Promise.
  return event.data.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});
```

I can't seem to extract the body of the request. It seems like it should be simple but I've tried all sorts of combinations of .body, .text and .json to no avail. Following the [Fetch API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) as instructed I couldn't figure out what the .body() method was giving me and .json() was undefined.

Other stack overflow questions seem to say that req.body.data should work, but it isn't for me.

Please help.

Comment: How are you making the request? Perhaps the problem is client-side

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to make the `fetch()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not getting **body** from **request** then it might be you have set GET for this service in your routes or make sure you have added [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) in your app.

You can trigger a function through an HTTP request with a request handler. This allows you to invoke a function through the following supported HTTP methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, and OPTIONS.

The request object gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request sent by the client, and the response object gives you a way to send a response back to the client.

```
exports.date = onRequest(
    {timeoutSeconds: 1200, region: ["us-west1", "us-east1"]},
    (req, res) => {
// ...
});
```

In the date() function example, the function tests both the URL parameter and the body for a format value to set the date/time format to use:

```
let format = req.query.format;
format = req.body.format;
```

For more reference [Call functions via HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd)